# Neural network and batch learning

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I am new to neural networks and would like to find out when am I supposed to reduce the learning rate as opposed to the batch size.

I would understand that if the learning diverges, the learning rate would have to be reduced.

However, when do I reduce or increase the batch size? My guess is that if the loss fluctuates too much, it would be ideal to reduce the batch size?

Comment: I'm guessing [Data Science SE](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/) might be of more assistance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on datascience.SE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you increase the batch size, the gradient is more likely to point towards the right direction so that the (overall) error decreases. Especially compared to updating the weights after considering only a single example which results in a very random and noisy gradient.

Therefore, if the loss function fluctuates, you can do both: increase the batch size and decrease the learning rate. The drawback of a larger batch size is the higher computational cost per update. So if the training takes too long, see if it still converges with a smaller batch size.

You can read more [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140811/how-large-should-the-batch-size-be-for-stochastic-gradient-descent) or [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49528/batch-gradient-descent-versus-stochastic-gradient-descent). (Btw, https://stats.stackexchange.com/ is more suitable for theoretical questions which do not contain specific code implementations)

Answer (score 1):

The "correct" way to learn is to use all of your training data for every single step in your gradient descent. However, this takes bit of time to compute it as this is a really heavy function which is - most of the time - parameterized by the thousands of training examples.

The idea is that the error function / weight update looks similar enough when you leave a couple of your training examples out. This speeds the calculateion of the error function up. However, the drawback is that you might not go in the correct direction with some gradient descent steps. But it should be "almost" correct in most cases.

So the rationale is that even if you don't go completely in the correct direction, you can do a lot more steps in the same time so that it doesn't matter.

A very common choice for the mini-batch size is 128 or 256. The most extreme choice is usually called "stochastic gradient descent" and uses only 1 training example.

As so often in ML, it is a good idea to just try different values.